# AJAX returns random hash instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on live notification script.
I have managed to rend request to external file, but the script returns random hash instead of plain text...

This is my function that should get data from test.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "/test.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#responsecontainer").append(response);
                setTimeout(load, 5000)
            }
        });
    }

    load(); //if you don't want the click
   // $("#display").click(load); //if you want to start the display on click
});
</script>
```

And it should append to  the results.

This is the source of test.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Headerview</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $p = "<p>test</p>";
    echo $p;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I am getting... 
inGN^PtJRo(hi*I1HVb&pB0wJs(B)9rID*6O�Eyh6cngWD+93Zr$zYU

Comment: What happens if you just navigate to `/test.php` instead of calling it via ajax?

Comment: Remove the dataType property, it is set as this by default (not exactly to html, it is an "intelligent guess", check on it in the JQ docs if you wish) and set contentType to text/html .

Comment: It could be the character encoding - 2 bytes vs 1 byte characters.

Comment: If i navigate to /test.php I can see plain text displayed properly. Setting contentType and removing dataType did not help

Comment: Why is test.php returning a full html document?

Comment: epascarello it does not work either way

Comment: What is the exact URL you're using ? The beginning slash in `/test.php` makes the browser look for a test.php file at the root of the domain. 
E.g. if your ajax call is in`http://localhost/projectxxx/index.html` the browser will look for `http://localhost/test.php` instead of `http://localhost/projectxxx/test.php` and might go to a completely different file.

Comment: Benjamin C. yes file path was the problem  thank you

Answer (score 0):

The file path was the problem. I did not specify exact file path.
Thank you